# Determine the real numbers $a, b, c, d \in [1,3]$, knowing that the relation $(a + b + c + d)^2 = 3(a^2 + b^2 +c^2 + d^2)$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, square-numbers

**the question**

Determine the real numbers $a, b, c, d \in [1,3]$, knowing that the relation $(a + b + c + d)^2 = 3(a^2 + b^2 +c^2  + d^2)$.

**my idea**

$(a+b+c+d)^2=a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2+2(ab+ac+ad+bc+bd+cd)$

$=> 2(ab+ac+ad+bc+bd+cd)=2(a^2 + b^2 +c^2  + d^2)=> ab+ac+ad+bc+bd+cd=a^2 + b^2 +c^2  + d^2$

From here I've been trying to get it to a form where 0 will equal the product of some numbers but I didn't get to anything helpful.

I hope one of you can help me! Thank you!

Comment: Play around with $(a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-d)^2+(d-a)^2$ and the like

Comment: Can you find an (obvious) solution set? That will give you some indication of what to try. (EG I don't see how Hagen's idea could be easily applied.)

Comment: Try boundary points (I.e. a,b,c,d being 1 or 3)

Comment: @Eric I tried and i found the solution (1,1,1,3). I thought of trying modular arithmetic

Comment: @IONELABUCIU mod is not useful with $\Bbb R$

Comment: You need to somehow prove that $d=a+b+c$, but I don't know how (if d is the maximum element)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For $x \in \{a,b,c,d \}$, we have:
$$(x-1)(x-3) \le 0 \iff x^2 \le 4x-3 \tag{1}$$
Let us denote $S = a+b+c+d$, from $(1)$ and the assumption, we deduce that
$$\begin{align}
&S^2 = 3 \sum_{\text{sym}}a^2 \le3 \left( \sum_{\text{sym}}(4a-3)  \right) = 12S-36\\
\iff &(S-6)^2\le 0\\
\iff &S = 6  \tag{2}
\end{align}$$

So, $(a,b,c,d)$ must satisfy the equality of $(1)$ and the equality of $(2)$.

As we cannot have $2$ variables having value equal to $3$, it's easy to deduce that the largest variable must be equal to $3$ and the 3 smaller variables receive value of $1$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your idea! I understood everything till the part where $S=6=a+b+c+d$.  You said that only (1,1,1,3)  satisfies this but (1,1,2,2) also does and its not a solution. Can you please explain me? Thank you

Comment: @IONELABUCIU All $(a,b,c,d)$ must be either equal to $1$ or $3$ (according to $(1)$), so the value $2$ is not allowed. And as we have *at most* one variable equal to $3$ (it's easy to check that) and *at least* one variable equal to $3$ (it's also easy to check that), you can deduce the conclusion

Comment: @Macavity No, I meant the equality of $(1)$. I just edit to precise the answer.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. +1

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

Consider the function
$$3(a^2 + b^2 +c^2  + d^2)-(a+b+c+d)^2$$
It is strictly convex in each variable separately ( being quadratic with leading coefficient $>0$). Such a function, on a product of closed intervals,  achieves its maximum only at a vertex.

In this case the values at vertices are

$$3(1+1+1+1)-(1+1+1+1)^2=-4 \\
3(1+1+1+9)-(1+1+1+3)^2= 0\\
3(1+1+9+9)-(1+1+3+3)^2=-4\\
3(9+9+9+9)-(3+3+3+3)^2=-36$$

We conclude that $\{a,b,c,d\} = \{1,1,1,3\}$.

---

$\bf{Added:}$ Below explaining myself the neat solution of @NN2:

We [have](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%28a%2Bb%2Bc%2Bd-6%29%5E2%2B3%28%283-a%29%28a-1%29%2B%283-b%29%28b-1%29%2B%283-c%29%28c-1%29%2B%283-d%29%28d-1%29%29)

$$(a+b+c+d)^2-3(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2) =\\ =(a+b+c+d-6)^2 + 3 \sum (3-a)(a-1) \ge 0$$
with equality if and only if $a$, $b$, $c$, $d\in \{1,3\}$ and $a+b+c+d=6$, so one of them is $3$ and the others equal $1$.

Answer (score 0):

COMMENT.-Since $(3r+x)^2=3(3r^2+x^2)\iff r=\dfrac{x}{3}$ the only solution with three equal variables is $(a,b,c,d)=(1,1,1,3)$ and permutations since $\dfrac13$ and $\dfrac23$ are not allowed. Astonishing it would be the only solution. I neither affirm nor deny this statement in this simple comment (I suspect this is so).

Put for $a,b,c$ very small among allowed values, for example
$(a,b,c,d)=(1,1.01,1.01,x)$ which gives the equation $(3.02+x)^2=3(3.0402+x^2)$ whose solutions are $x=0$ and $x\gt3$ and for greater values the solutions wil be not allowed. I think
that what I suspect is true.